# hiding a UIView while moving it in animation

Tags: ios, xcode

I have some animation that does some rotation using beginAnimations.
I want to hide the UIview in question, of course I tried changing the hidden property but nothing happened.
Here is the code

```
 CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( angelToRotate(-90));
[UIView beginAnimations: @"" context: NULL];
self.view.hidden = TRUE;
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.4];
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(self.view.transform, rotation);
self.view.hidden = FALSE;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I also tried changing the alpha on the view, but still nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( angelToRotate(-90));   
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^
{
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(self.view.transform, rotation);
    self.view.alpha = 0.0;
}
completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
    self.view.alpha = 1.0;
}];
```

Or:

---

```
CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( angelToRotate(-90));
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context: NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(self.view.transform, rotation);
self.view.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

---

```
- (void) animationDidStop: (NSString *) animationID finished: (NSNumber *) finished context: (void *) context
{
    self.view.alpha = 1.0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is blocks. They are easy to use.
For example, we must set self.view.alpha = 1.0; after animation will be complete. It is possible using [UIView beginAnimations:context:], but a little more complicated.

Comment: well how did they help, can you please elaborate on this? I am trying to absorb the solution better.

Comment: I am add alternative way using [UIView beginAnimations:context:].
You can compare these two methods.

Answer (score 0):

as a start try taking away the self.view.hidden = TRUE 
IF I get your code correctly, animation should disappear and reappear after .4 seconds?

Hiding and Showing on the same function doesn't work that way.

You could call another function that specifically does self.view.hidden = FALSE